# create custom login in yii2 without default database table

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

How we can create login form with custom databse table in yii2. I have one  table called User and have fields (Id(p.k),UserName,Password). I want to login using above(User) Table . So how can i do this.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: How password is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the advanced yii2 template https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced. It already has exactly what you want h besides the table name being lowercase.

And for the people that will tell me that the link can change... this is the main repository of a framework... it will not change.

Comment: yes i know this but i am not understanding whole process of login in yii2 . yii2 flowing many step for inbuilt login . I am willing to convert an existing core php project in yii2. So i  want to know can we create user login as we do in core  php using our custom database table.

Comment: Your custom database table is almost identical to the yii2 one. Understand the Login process from Yii, see what is in each class and you will easily change it to your own.